# Why api github search don't find all repositories

Tags: json, rest, github

Why does the github API not show me the list of all repositories?

Example:

https://github.com/github

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:github+sort:updated

Using the first link we can see 296 repositories, using second I receive "total_count": 173. How can I search all 296 repositories using the github API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that API hides archived repos from the results. `+archived:true` that should show you another 42 or so. But that doesn't add upto 296 so I use the user API (https://api.github.com/users/github/repos) instead which can return more that one type of repository at a time.

It seems theres's some dependency on the `search` API that hides some repos that is not documented.

https://api.github.com/users/github/repos?type=all&per_page=100 ==> 100
https://api.github.com/users/github/repos?type=all&per_page=100&page=2  ==> 100
https://api.github.com/users/github/repos?type=all&per_page=100&page=3  ==> 96

```
curl https://api.github.com/users/github/repos\?type\=all\&per_page\=100 | jq length
curl https://api.github.com/users/github/repos\?type\=all\&per_page\=100\&page\=2 | jq length
curl https://api.github.com/users/github/repos\?type\=all\&per_page\=100\&page\=3 | jq length
```

Sorted by updated

```
sds-users:() ➜  (11/04 19:18) /tmp curl "https://api.github.com/users/github/repos?type=all&per_page=10&sort=updated" | jq '.[].updated_at'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 54509  100 54509    0     0  76340      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 76450
"2019-04-11T18:15:05Z"
"2019-04-11T18:05:00Z"
"2019-04-11T18:02:57Z"
"2019-04-11T17:41:47Z"
"2019-04-11T17:35:55Z"
"2019-04-11T16:46:28Z"
"2019-04-11T16:20:20Z"
"2019-04-11T16:17:09Z"
"2019-04-11T15:48:31Z"
"2019-04-11T15:27:31Z"
sds-users:() ➜  (11/04 19:18) /tmp
```

Comment: Thank you. I want get this repositories sorted due to update date. It is possible to sort it and display on first page the neewest and on third page the oldest? Or rather i must sort it in my own programm?

Comment: Yes, you can use sort and direction filters too. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories

Comment: It will work?https://api.github.com/users/github/repos?type=all&per_page=100&sort=updated   EDIT: "It work" mean that i recive sorted all types of repositories?

Comment: According to GitHub it's supposed to but I wouldn't bet on it. Let me do an independent verification.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work on a sample of 10 repos I ran.

Answer (score 1):

The [public webpage](https://github.com/github) includes archived repositories. The [API query](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:github+sort:updated) does not.